# Nginx shows error page from time to time

Tags: 14.04, nginx, vps

I am running a VPS on digitalocean. I have daily traffic of 500 unique users. I was having CPU and RAM utilization problems on Apache. Now I am using Nginx because it's lightweight. My CPU and RAM is under control but still Nginx shows an error message from time to time, which I believe is due to load/wrong configuration.

I am getting this error in my log files:

```
ngx_slab_alloc() failed: no memory in SSL session
```

I have the following configuration for my nginx server:

```
keepalive_timeout   20;
ssl_session_timeout 7200m;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:150m;
ssl_stapling on;
ssl_stapling_verify on;
add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;
```

What is the right configuration for me, considering I am running a VPS with 1Gb RAM?

Would using a database sessions table (as in Laravel) solve my problem, independent from the Nginx configuration?

Comment: Have you talked to _Digitalocean_ ?

Comment: change `ssl_session_timeout 1440m` and lets see

Answer (score 0):

Reduce ssl_session_timeout and ssl_session_cache values. Please check the link http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#optimization for nginx https server configuration and server optimization.